# Best Way to Convert 1D String Array to a 2D Char Array in Java (Eclipse)

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, char, wordsearch

For a Word Search Game in Java, I am asking the user to enter as many words as they like (they will type a single 'q' if they want to stop adding more words), and this input is stored in an Array List, which is then converted to a 1D Array called `words.` I then call on a method in main to begin the game. Here is the code snippet:

```js
System.out.println("Grid of the game");
for(char[] j : letterGrid) {
    System.out.println(j);
  }
   System.out.println("Search for these words...\n");
    for(String j : words) {
      System.out.print(j + ", ");
    }  
    System.out.print("Enter the Word: ");
    String word = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Row Number: ");
    int row = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
     //matching the word using regex
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(word, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(letterGrid[row-1]);
```

letterGrid is a 2D char Array, but at the line where it says: `Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(letterGrid[row-1]);` an error happens, and it says: `The method matcher(CharSequence) in the type Pattern is not applicable for the arguments.` I tried changing my program and turning letterGrid into a 1D String array, and it works fine for that, but not for a 2D char array. I fill letterGrid with random letters and the user words (horizontally, vertically, or diagonally. None backwards).

I am stuck on this and I am currently looking for ways get my problem fixed, but I figured I could ask here as well since people here provide good advice and suggestions. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Reading through a code dump is effortful and annoying.

Comment: Alright. I will remove a little of my code and make my question and description less wordy.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only acceptable argument to matcher is string
&
the quickest way to convert char to string is:

```
char c = 'a';
String s = String.valueOf(c);
```

so, you can do this:

```
String s = String.valueOf(letterGrid[row-1]);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
```

Comment: I tried this, but my program still wants me to "explicitly convert the char[] to a String" The program underlines the letterGrid[row-1] part as yellow and says exactly that.

Comment: @YashviShah i have edited my answer. please follow along.

Comment: @YashviShah I hope it worked for you. please consider accepting my answer if it did so others can benefit too. thanks!

Comment: I just tried it out. Fortunately, it worked (: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @YashviShah happy to help